# I am trying to update user identity of twilio user but not working

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-chat

I am using Twilio and I want to update user identity but it is not updating, while other keys update is working fine like friendlyName, etc.

Can you please help me.

Here is my code

```
$twilio->chat->v2->services(env('TWILIO_SERVICE_SID'))
                     ->users('US2424637a5007483eb4bb781574be82aa')
                     ->update([
                                  "Identity" => "smith",//not working
                                  "friendlyName" => "peter smith"
                              ]
                     );
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update IDENTITY of user as per Twilio, yes this is only method to update user resources it will work for other data but for IDENTITY it will not work.

You can update user data in Attributes.